# Set value of XML node as field on C# model in XML deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I am looking to properly deserialize some XML.

Part of the XML looks like this:

```
<Keys>
    <Key>
        <Name>Test 1</Name>
        <KeyValues>
            <KeyValue Offered="true" Order="1">One</KeyValue>
            <KeyValue Offered="true" Order="2">Two</KeyValue>
            <KeyValue Offered="true" Order="3">Three</KeyValue>
            <KeyValue Offered="true" Order="4">Four</KeyValue>
        </KeyValues>                            
    </Key>                      
    <Key>
        <Name>Test 2</Name>
        <KeyValues>
            <KeyValue Offered="true">One</KeyValue>
        </KeyValues>                            
    </Key>
</Keys>
```

and I would like to deserialize each KeyValue from that into a C# object that looks like this:

```
public class KeyValue
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Order { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public bool Offered { get; set; }
}
```

This is (roughly) the code that I am using to deserialize:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));

using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    myObject = (MyObject)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

This is almost working properly. No exceptions are thrown and Order and Offered are correctly set, but I'd like the One, Two, Three, etc from the KeyValues in my XML to go into the Value field on my model.

Is this possible? If so, how could I do it?

Comment: So you're saying that `Value` in `KeyValue` is not getting populated?

Comment: @Robert, yes, that is correct. I'd like it to get populated with the value of the KeyValue node. It works when I add a Value node underneath it, but I was hoping I could get this to work and not ask to have this XML structure changed.

Comment: Need an Object that will hold a collection of KeyValues and it will need a serialiser and also for Keys.

Comment: @Tony, I believe I have all that in "MyObject." I know this because I have everything but this one field deserializing properly. I think the other stuff in "MyObject" will just add noise to the question, especially because the object is filled with industry specific jargon. Hope it's not confusing.

Comment: Plug your XML in [here](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/) and look at the generated classes.

Comment: My guess is you need [`[XmlText]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute?view=netframework-4.8) on that `Value` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a look at [this website](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/) per Robert Harvey's comment, I realized that what I was missing was an `[XmlText]` attribute over my Value field. I added that, tested, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use serialization in this case because it would require my classes then other methods.  See xml linq solution below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication110
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<Key> keys = doc.Descendants("Key").Select(x => new Key()
            {
                Name = (string)x.Element("Name"),
                Values = x.Descendants("KeyValue").Select(y => new KeyValue() {
                    Value = (string)y,
                    Offered = (bool)y.Attribute("Offered"),
                    Order  = (int?)y.Attribute("Order")
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
        }

    }
    public class Key
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<KeyValue> Values { get;set;}
    }
    public class KeyValue
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public int? Order { get; set; }
        public bool Offered { get; set; }
    }



}
```